# Invalid http response 634, 638 - Github webhook

Tags: ruby, github, sinatra, webhooks, ngrok

I have a github webhook, it send a post to the url I have set which is not a problem. I have this weird error which I cant find anywhere. It says

`Invalid HTTP Response: 634`

There is no definition for `Response code 634` anywhere? Anyone have any idea about this?

I'm using ruby sinatra to fetch the post and ngrok as my server on localhost itself. Initial requests worked fine.

Once I added code to write the post received to a file in my ruby script, it started giving me this 634 response code, however, *it works fine*. I'm just curious as to what does the error code imply. I have no issues with my code, it works fine.

Let me know if you need more information.

[image: Response 634]

**EDIT:**

Earlier one was the response I received when I pushed some changes done to a text file.

Based on [mudasobwa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa) comment, I tried again. This time I checked in a .java file and weirdly I get a different `Invalid response 638` this time
[image: Invalid response for java file]

I'm not sure whats going on. My server is able to receive the post anyway though.

Comment: It looks like it interprets the content type improperly. Would you mind to try with another file? — my guess is that those are first three bytes of response or like and you should receive another three “digits” on another file.

Comment: @mudasobwa Sorry I  didnt understand. try with another file as in? Could you please elaborate, I definitely will try.

Comment: I meant with another push content, triggering hook. E.g. commit and push another file, or a bundle or files, or like.

Comment: @mudasobwa Update my question. Earlier one was on a txt file and tried a new commit by pushing a `java file` and the invalid response code now changed.

Comment: Well, my suggestion was likely correct. _Some_ handler treats the content type improperly. This “code” is nothing but the first three bytes of response, or github invented it’s own style of responding with their API. Unfortunately, I can’t suggest smth more meaningful, since I personally never met the case. I would suggest you to either live with this since everything works, or _Wireshark_ your network to examine what’s going on more thoroughly. Good luck!